# Where to Log application info when the application is deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-diagnostics

Hi I am new to this but previously, I was using Log4Net successfully to log info and errors.  Now when we are migrating to the cloud and hosting the app in Azure. Where should I store the the files.  Currently the root folder is C:\Log\LogfileFortheapp.txt.

1. Not sure can I create a folder within the solution and store the files there? If so how I give a path in the web.Config file?
2. Also if I could Azure logs, it seems there are too many tools.  But for the moment I need to use one which can store the error or information that I am currently logging into Log4net. So any suggestion please?

Comment: Look at Azure Monitor.